# When do I use "livestock is" and "livestock are"?

Tags: grammatical-number

Honestly, I know the answer is most likely going to be some form of "it depends", so here's the context I'm using the phrase noun in:

> the livestock are acting up and now I need to...
>
> the livestock is acting up and now I need to...

I know there are instances when "livestock" feels more singular than plural, but in my use case I'm leaning plural. I'm just not sure.

Any help and other examples are appreciated

Comment: You can find a lot of usage examples here: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=livestock+Is%2Clivestock+are&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Clivestock%20Is%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Blivestock%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLivestock%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Clivestock%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Blivestock%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLivestock%20are%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ODO defines livestock as a mass noun, and none of its many examples has either *is* or *are* following the word:

> **livestock** *noun (mass noun)*
>   Farm animals regarded as an asset.
>   ‘markets for the trading of livestock’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/livestock)

Interestingly, though, [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/livestock) provides this pair of examples:

> a market where livestock are bought and sold
>   a market where livestock is bought and sold

M-W's [learner's dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/livestock) provides a little more information, noting both plural and noncount usage of the word *livestock*, with the above examples repeated.

So if you're treating the livestock as a (plural) set of animals, use *livestock are*, and if you're treating the animals as a collective (massed) group, use *livestock is*.

Comment: I guess it comes down to understanding when I'm using it as a plural and when as a collective (seems obvious, but I guess I just need more examples and patterns to develop this judgment).

Would you recommend I replace livestock with an animal set noun (kettle of hawks, pod of dolphins, murder of crows) just to test the usage? What about substitutes for the collective form?

Comment: Here's a test you can try: replace *livestock* with *group*, then with *individuals*. If *group* fits better, use *livestock* as a mass noun; if *individuals* fits better, use it as a plural noun.

Comment: The term 'a plural noun' is unhelpful. 'Furniture' is [a] usually non-count ('[two] different furnitures' is rare, though sometimes seen in the antiques domain), [b] of singular form (contrast the rare plural form 'furnitures'), [c] takes singular agreement ('the furniture they sell **is** ...'), but [d] is etically countable (3 chairs and 2 tables, say).